# Bootstrap compiled less files not the same as given css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I need to make a few adjustments to the bootstrap css I'm using and I was trying to play around with the given less files, but compiling them does not give the same result as the provided css files from the bootstrap website. To compile I used the command lessc bootstrap.less file.css, after reading that this .less file is importing everything else and it is the way to compile multiple less files into one. My resulted css file has lacks a considerable amount of features, in comparison to the given bootstrap.css I can download from the website. How could I get the same css from the less files?

Comment: What features are missing?  Their `bootstrap.css` file should match the one that is compiled via LESS if all the files are there.  Make sure what you are looking for isn't part of their `docs.css` file, because that includes customizations they made for their docs pages and are not part of the core of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have updated to the latest version.

I believe version 3.0 should suffice?